# Send email only when offline IP/Computer is not responding to ping test

Tags: powershell

I want to modify the below script, so the email can be sent out when the ping is not replying or server / IP address is offline.

The issue with the below script is that it does not send an email when the IP/Computername in the `$FullServerFile` is offline but it sends email on both conditions.

```
# Email settings
$Email = @{
    # specify who gets notified
    To = 'xxxxxx@test.com', 'yyyy@test.com'
    # specify where the notifications come from
    From = 'Server_Online@test.com'
    # specify the SMTP server
    SmtpServer = 'mailrelay.test.net'
}

$DownServerFile = "C:\DownServers.txt"
$FullServerFile = "C:\ServerList.txt"
# Create empty arrays for offline server lists
$PreviousDownServers = @()
$CurrentDownServers = @()
If (Test-Path -Path $DownServerFile) { $PreviousDownServers = Get-Content C:\TEMP\DownServers.txt }
Get-Content -Path $FullServerFile | ForEach-Object {
    $Server = $_
    if (test-Connection -ComputerName $Server -Count 2 -Quiet)
    {
        write-Host "$Server is alive and Pinging " -ForegroundColor Green
        #Send email if this server was down previously, but is now up
        if ($PreviousDownServers -notcontains $Server)
        {
            $date = (Get-Date).ToString('dddd dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm tt ') + "$([System.TimeZoneInfo]::FindSystemTimeZoneById((Get-WmiObject win32_timezone).StandardName))"
            $Subject = "$server Ping Monitor success" + $date
            $body = "$Server is now responding to ping."
            Send-MailMessage -Body $body -Subject $subject @Email
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $CurrentDownServers += $Server
        #Send email only if this is the first time the server is down
        if ($PreviousDownServers -notcontains $Server)
        {
            $date = (Get-Date).ToString('dddd dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm tt ') + "$([System.TimeZoneInfo]::FindSystemTimeZoneById((Get-WmiObject win32_timezone).StandardName))"
            $Subject = "$server [$($((Resolve-DnsName -Name $server -Type A).IPAddress))] Ping Monitor failure - $date "
            $body = "$Server is not responding to ping."
            Send-MailMessage -Body $body -Subject $subject @Email
        }
    }
    
}
$CurrentDownServers | Out-File $DownServerFile
```

Comment: So which specific part of script fails? Have you run it in debugger?

Comment: The ask isn't clear. Do you want it to email every time the ping fails? the way it is now it emails when it wasn't already down...

Comment: The first test where the server was down previously but is up now is wrong, should be `if ($PreviousDownServers -contains $Server)` (you used `-notcontains` there). Also, on my Dutch machine this `[System.TimeZoneInfo]::FindSystemTimeZoneById((Get-WmiObject win32_timezone).StandardName)` doesn't work. Don't you just mean `(Get-WmiObject win32_timezone).StandardName` ??

Comment: Yes, that I wanted to achieve is send email every time the IP is offline. This script will be executed with a scheduled task every 10 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented, I think the first test to see if the server was previously down uses `-notcontains` by mistake.

For me (Dutch machine) `[System.TimeZoneInfo]::FindSystemTimeZoneById((Get-WmiObject win32_timezone).StandardName)` won't work, because `(Get-WmiObject win32_timezone).StandardName` returns the name localized and that does not match the TimeZone ID.

Also, I wonder why you keep two `DownServers.txt` files, where there is only the need for the one file that you are updating..

Concatenating to an array as in `$CurrentDownServers += $Server` should be avoided, because on each iteration the entire array gets recreated in memory and is time consuming.

I'd suggest changing the code a bit to

```
# Email settings
$Email = @{
    # specify who gets notified
    To = 'xxxxxx@test.com', 'yyyy@test.com'
    # specify where the notifications come from
    From = 'Server_Online@test.com'
    # specify the SMTP server
    SmtpServer = 'mailrelay.test.net'
}

$DownServerFile = "C:\DownServers.txt"
$FullServerFile = "C:\ServerList.txt"
$TimeZoneName   = (Get-WmiObject Win32_TimeZone).StandardName

$PreviousDownServers = if (Test-Path -Path $DownServerFile -PathType Leaf) { 
                            Get-Content -Path $DownServerFile | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' }
                       } 
                       else { @() }
$AllServers = Get-Content -Path $FullServerFile | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' }

$CurrentDownServers = foreach ($Server in $AllServers) {
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $Server -Count 2 -Quiet) {
        Write-Host "$Server is alive and Pinging" -ForegroundColor Green
        #Send email if this server was down previously, but is now up
        if ($PreviousDownServers -contains $Server) {
            $date = "{0:dddd dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm tt} $TimeZoneName" -f (Get-Date)
            $Email['Subject'] = "$Server Ping Monitor success" + $date
            $Email['Body']    = "$Server is now responding to ping."
            Send-MailMessage @Email
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "$Server is down" -ForegroundColor Red
        # output the server to be collected in $CurrentDownServers
        $Server
        # Send email only if this is the first time the server is down *Commented out*
        # if ($PreviousDownServers -notcontains $Server) {
            $date = "{0:dddd dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm tt} $TimeZoneName" -f (Get-Date)
            $Email['Subject'] = "$Server [$($((Resolve-DnsName -Name $Server -Type A).IPAddress))] Ping Monitor failure - $date"
            $Email['Body']    = "$Server is not responding to ping."
            Send-MailMessage -Body $body -Subject $subject @Email
        # }
    }  
}
# re-write the $DownServerFile with servers that are down now or delete the file if all servers are up
if (!$CurrentDownServers) { 
    Remove-Item -Path $DownServerFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
else {
    $CurrentDownServers | Set-Content $DownServerFile -Force
}
```

Comment: thank you for the update and assistance in this thread.
however, the two offline IPs but but the script above did not send out any email?
10.10.10.1 is alive and Pinging
33.33.33.33 is down
5.6.7.8 is down

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer Well, apparently  the ip that is alive was alive before this run and the test is to send an email **only** if this IP was down last time. As for the servers that are down, the test **only** sends email if they were not already in the Downservers.txt file (effectively only if this is the first time they did not respond to ping). Try with an initial DownServers.txt containing `10.10.10.1`. This should trigger an email "10.10.10.1 is now responding to ping." and two other mails containing "33.33.33.33 is not responding to ping." and "5.6.7.8 is not responding to ping."

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer I did however changed the script a little now to remove any empty elements from the files we read in.

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer Ah, I misunderstood the question. If as I understand now, you want to send an email every time a server is off-line, then just remove the second `if` condition. I have updated the answer and commented those lines out.